# How to know all the permission I have in a GCP I have?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-iam

I have been added and granted viewer access to project however almost every page I open shows that I don't have permission to view this particular GCP service of that particular project. How can I know all the permission I have for a certain project?

Comment: Menu > IAM & Admin > IAM

Comment: Roles about bound to a resource with an identity as part of a policy. Therefore you need the correct roles to read the resource policy. There are many resources in GCP (project, storage, KMS, Functions, Run, etc.) Based on your question, you do not have those permissions. The command to read a Project's IAM policy is **gcloud projects get-iam-policy**. If that command fails, then you will not be able to determine which resources you have been granted roles (permissions) to access.

Answer (score 1):

Use asset inventory [search IAM policies](https://cloud.google.com/asset-inventory/docs/searching-iam-policies)

```
gcloud asset search-all-iam-policies \
  --scope='projects/<PROJECT_ID>' \
  --query='policy:"<YOUR_EMAIL>"'
```